# Reading a file with different variable types into a structure in c

Tags: c, string, file, fgets, scanf

I'm trying to figure out how to read a file that contains different variable types. In this case the .txt file is formatted like this.

```
MCD
McDonald's
20.45
BK
Burger King
30.47
DQ
Dairy Queen
25.63
```

It goes in a pattern of two strings followed by a double. My code to read in the file is as follows

```
int fillArray(struct Stock * array, FILE * fin)
{
   int i = 0;
   char buff[MAX];
   while(fgets(buff, MAX, fin) != NULL)
   {
       strcpy(array[i].symbol, buff);
       fgets(buff, MAX, fin);
       strcpy(array[i].companyName, buff);
       fscanf(fin, "%lf", &array[i].currentPrice);
       i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

When I go to print the structure I get this output.

```
MCD
McDonald's
20.45
BK
0.00Burger Kin30.47
30.47
0.00DQ
Dairy Queen
25.63

0.00
```

It seems things fall apart as soon as a string with spaces is read. Does anyone know what might be causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the number is read using

```
fscanf(fin, "%lf", &array[i].currentPrice);
```

the newline character is still there in the input stream. The next call to `fgets()` reads only the newline into the array.

Add the following to skip till the end of the line after that.

```
int c;
while ( ( c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n');
```

Comment: Hey! That was the problem! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sturminator, you are welcome. Glad I was able to help.